# Replacing email placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.get("template.html", function( data ) {
  //replace placeholder
  //append
  $('editor').append($(data));
});
```

My `template.html` is an email template consisting of different placeholders like `##name##` etc. I tried to replace, but my data is not a string, so `data.replace('##name##',name)` doesn’t work. What’s the correct way of doing that?

Comment: "my data is not a string". What object do you receive in `data`? It is an HTML file, so, you should get a plain string in `data`.

Comment: @CD.. What I can't use client side to do it?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev but why it doesn't work then?

Comment: What does it return if you use `console.log(data);` that will give you a better idea of the error. Your question isn't formulated very well...

Answer (score 0):

From [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

> The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element, text string, JavaScript file, or JSON object, depending on the MIME type of the response

Open the web developer console (f12), look at the "network" panel, and see what the "headers" are in the request made to `template.html`

It probably is an XML root element, then to replace, you can do something like this

```
var str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data)
str = str.replace('##name##', name)
```

Answer (score 0):

if `editor` is the id of the `div` you want to append to, use `$("#editor").append()`. Also, the replace function the way you are using will replace only 1st instance of `##name##`, leaving all subsequent instances without replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why your `data` is not a string.

I have tried your code, and it just works.

> **index.html**

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.get('email.html', function(data) {
                console.log(1, typeof data);
                console.log(2, data);
                console.log(3, data.replace('##title##', 'This is a so-called title'));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

> **email.html**

```
<!-- email.html -->
<div id="email">
    <p class="title">##title##</p>
    <p class="subject">##subject##</p>
    <div id="content">##content##</div>
</div>
```

**And the output in chrome is**:

```
1 "string"
2 "<div id="email">
    <p class="title">##title##</p>
    <p class="subject">##subject##</p>
    <div id="content">##content##</div>
</div>
"
3 "<div id="email">
    <p class="title">This is a so-called title</p>
    <p class="subject">##subject##</p>
    <div id="content">##content##</div>
</div>
"
```

IMO, the reason you can not get the expected result is that you may use the `file:///` scheme to open your html in browsers to do cross origin request (`$.get`). And you can get this error in console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/ooops/Sites/aaa/email.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

You can put these files in your `www`(server) directory and access with `localhost` in browser. Go and check it, hope this helps.